# Jmeter assertions with a file

Tags: jmeter, response, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, assertion

I have a Jmeter script which compares the actual response Body with a expected Response body I have added as "Pattern to Test" in Response Assertion.

Is there a way , I can save this body to a external file and compare that with the Actual response in jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can save JMeter Variable into a file using [__StringToFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringToFile)
2. Alternatively you can save Sampler's response into a file using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer)
3. The file contents can be read in the Assertion via [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to save the response to the file.

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.io.FileWriter;

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("file_name.json",false);
    fstream.write(response);
    fstream.close();
```

Hope you have 2nd json from which you want to compare current json in a file.
Yo can use below code to compare between two json files or **you can simply use BeyonCompare tool** to compare different types of json,text etc.

To compare two different json files

```
def json1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(document1)
def json2 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(document2)

assert map1 == map2
```